# Displaying a QtGui.QMainWindow object without quiting the script afterwards

Tags: python, pyqt

I've wrote an object that inherits from QtGui.QMainWindow (python/pyqt). It displays an image and gives me more controls. I want to use this object as additional way to plot figures in the flow of the script (like plt.show())

The problem is that displaying this object involves a code like this:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = ImageViewerWindow(result) #ImageViewerWindow inherits from QtGui.QMainWindow
mainWin.show()
app.exec_()
```

After the "app" was closed, I can't display additional window. Is there a way to display this window, wait for it to close, and then display another window without explicitly using signals?

(signals can be used behind the scenes but I don't want to complicate the user that want to display the image with minimal number of commands)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiet way, another way will be catching the closing event in your window.

```
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ImageViewerWindow(result) #ImageViewerWindow inherits from QtGui.QMainWindow
    mainWin.show()
    differentWindow = dW()  # your other window
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(lambda: differentWindow.show())
    app.exec_()
```

Another way would be adding the closeEvent method to your window class

```
class ImageViewerWindow(...): # or QMainWindow
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        differentWindow = dW()  # your other window
        differentWindow.show()
```

Comment: For obvious reasons, you cannot use [aboutToQuit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) (clue is in the name). The second suggestion is also a quite dubious: how would the user ever be able to quit the application? (And you need to keep a reference to the new window, to stop it being garbage-collected).

Comment: Thanks, but this is using signals. It's not an intuitive flow for my purposes. I would like the flow of the script to be: some operations --> open window + wait to close --> additional calculations/operations --> open window, etc...

Comment: @ekhumoro seems like the window closes normally after my closeEvent method.